# Why do application need serial number?

Tags: android, security

I use [XPrivacy](http://repo.xposed.info/module/biz.bokhorst.xprivacy) module on my android mobile. After installation of some app, when I check permissions that application is asking, 'almost all' the time application ask for "Identification" which I suppose is generally is serial number of my device. I have few noob questions on this

1. Why do android application need serial number of my device ?
2. Why it stops working when I block access to it (*it stops working initially but works after 3-4 times you open app*)
3. What will company do with that information (I know it will vary according to their privacy policy but what do they do *in general*?)

Answer (score 0):

According to [https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73361/what-does-serial-and-proc-permissions-stand-for][1] "Serial permission allows the app to grab a unique identifier for for your phone." I think it can be applied on user behavior stats report upload, to identify each different mobile user.

The reason why it stops working when you deny the permission request from the app is because it can't get the permission and some of it's function might throw some run time exception and cause the app crashes or stopped if the app developer handles the run time exception properly.